# CMake Error: The source directory /home/pi/opencv-3.0.0/build/BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON does not exist

Tags: cmake

I ran the following lines

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.0.0/modules \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON
```

and got this error

```
CMake Error: The source directory /home/pi/opencv-3.0.0/build/BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON does not exist`
```

How could this be solved?

Answer (score 9):

The last argument to the `cmake` command needs to be a directory containing a `CMakeList.txt` file.

Usually that's either the current directory `.` or the parent directory `..` in the case of an out-of-source build where you are running the command from a separate `build` subdirectory:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.0.0/modules \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

[I suspect you are following instructions that used `..` and misinterpreted it as standing in for an arbitrary list of `-D` options rather than an actual directory argument]

Comment: that was my problem, i left out the ..